# Mixed effect modelling

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

In R, I wish to perform linear mixed effect models by assigning the terms QY, ALOS and expenditure as fixed variables and Month as a random variable. Is this the right format to perform the analysis? (Note: QY stands for quality of life, ALOS refers to average length of stay, Expenditure refers to the total expenditure borne by the patient during his surgery, DC refers to direct cost and IC is the indirect cost)
The dataset looks like:

```
head(sur_2019)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Month     ALOS Expenditure    IC    DC   QY
  <chr>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 January   3.2        17800  4560 13240 0.0984
2 February  4.86       26790  5000 21790 1.08  
3 March     4.2        42500  7500 35000 0.843 
4 April     3.5        25000  5850 19150 0.234 
5 May       3.5        80000 16100 63900 0.385 
6 June      3.07       22780  6780 16000 0.120 
Analysis:

m1<-lme(QY~ALOS+Expenditure+Month,
          data=sur_2019, fixed=QY~ALOS+Expenditure, 
          random=~1|Month, na.action = na.omit,
          start=c(QY=1, ALOS=1, Expenditure=100))

Error in lme(QY ~ ALOS + Expenditure + Month, data = sur_2019, fixed = QY ~ : unused argument (start = c(QY = 1, ALOS = 1, Expenditure = 100))

Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

Comment: What is your research question ? What is the size of your data ? Why do you want to fit month as random ? –

Comment: The variable QY follows the weibull distribution and variable expenditure follows the gamma distribution then can we fit a mixed model in order to find out the random and fixed effects in the given dataset. @RobertLong my research question is to find the best linear estimable function for QY. The size of the data is 350. Since the observations (QY, Expenditure) were varying over different months so i choose month as a random variable. Thanks